# Set asset uploader from frontend entry form

Tags: assets, upload, frontend-form

Now that Craft [keeps track](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/3553) of which user uploaded an asset, I'm wondering if it's possible to set this information when an asset is uploaded via a frontend entry form. I have a form that includes an asset field and I would like the assets that are created to be "owned" by the current user. Can this be done via a hidden input, or would I need to hook into an asset event?

Comment: This is actually a [bug](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/6456) in Craft. Fixed as of 3.5.8 or 3.4.30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using an event to accomplish this:

```
use yii\base\Event;
use craft\elements\Asset;
use craft\events\AssetEvent;

Event::on(Asset::class, Asset::EVENT_BEFORE_HANDLE_FILE, function (AssetEvent $event) {
    $asset = $event->sender;
    // This does not work because it doesn't set the `uploaderId` property on the asset
    // $asset->setUploader(Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity()); // Doesn't work, bug?
    
    // So I just set the `uploaderId` directly
    if (is_null($asset->uploaderId)) {
        $asset->uploaderId = Craft::$app->getUser()->getId();
    }
});
```